# How to disable the depth buffer?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0, depth-buffer

I don't see a `RenderState` as a member in the `GraphicsDevice` class, which is where the functions for disabling the depth buffer used to be. Anyone know how this is done with this new 4.0 API?

It would be great if I could somehow access a full `RenderState`-like class somewhere..  `GraphicsDevice` seems to have gotten some of it, but not nearly all!

Answer (score 2):

Ah.. I would be setting `GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState` to an instance of `DepthStencilState` with any number of properties set. Seems like the `RenderState` was broken into a bunch of other states. I was looking for in the individual properties inside of `GraphicsDevice` before, but they seem to be better organized now for easier state management.

```
depthState = new DepthStencilState();
depthState.DepthBufferEnable = true; /* Enable the depth buffer */
depthState.DepthBufferWriteEnable = true; /* When drawing to the screen, write to the depth buffer */

GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = depthState;
```

Comment: Yes.  But make sure you create state objects once (not in your draw method).  Read Shawn for details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are a number of pre-built state objects that cover many common scenarios.  In this case, you can use DepthStencilState.None to disable depth buffering, and DepthStencilState.Default to enable writing (as in your example here).